# to include - transitive/intransitive/ambitransitive?

Tags: meaning

> 1 We decided to include only those artists who had written works
> within the last five years.
>
> 2 This dish doesn't include many ingredients.

Dictionaries say that "INCLUDE" is transitive. But I can see a difference between the two sentences in regards of the way the INCLUDE is used there.

I think it works differently.

> 3 We included you in the list of newbies. (The subject includes an object in something else)
>
> 4 This list includes newbies. (The subject includes something in itself)

If the difference doesn't come down to being ambitransitive what does it come down to? Maybe I am missing the right term which labels this phenomenon?

Comment: The prepositional phrase merely supplies some additional information making explicit the details of the inclusion. It doesn't alter the transitivity.   "She punched him *in the nose* so we included her *on the team.*"   *The list included her* and *We included her* are just a change of subject, not a change of transitivity.

Comment: I don't follow you. The verb "include" can be both transitive or intransitive, depending on its complement. In both examples 3. and 4. it's transitive because it has the NPs "you" and "newbies" respectively as objects. Note that in 3. the PP "in the list of newbies" is not part of the object.

Comment: Give me an example of it being intransitive

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference in meaning. In sentences 2 and 4, the subject ("the dish" and "this list") includes the direct object within itself, but in sentences 1 and 3, the subject ("we") includes the direct object in some other container. (I'm ignoring the word "not", which isn't important for the point that I'm making.) Sometimes dictionaries point out such differences in meaning, but sometimes they don't. I'm not aware of any specific term that refers to that difference.

Note that there is no difference in syntax. In each case the subject performs the action of including on the direct object. Therefore, "include" is transitive in all of your sentences, consistent with what is shown in major dictionaries. Sentence 3 adds a prepositional phrase ("in the list of newbies") to indicate where the direct object is being included, but that is optional. (Note, however, that if it were left out, then the meaning would be ambiguous without context.)

Comment: Hi! How are you doing? I upvoted your good answer! I wrote an answer and the community downvoted it. I believe that my answer is correct! Could you please read it carefully and tell me your opinion? [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343962/which-is-the-subject-of-generalising/343970#343970